# Concatenating lists using template metaprogramming in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I've created a new type called IntList, which represents a list of integers. This was made by using templates:

```
template<int...>
struct IntList;

template<int h, int... t>
struct IntList<h, t...>{
    constexpr static int head = h;
    typedef IntList<t...> next;
    constexpr static int size = sizeof...(t) + 1;
    constexpr static bool empty = false;
};

template<>
struct IntList<>{
    constexpr static int size = 0;
    constexpr static bool empty = true;
};
```

For example, IntList<1,2,3,4> is a list of 4 elements - 1,2,3,4.

```
IntList<1,2,3,4>::head; //Should be 1
IntList<1,2,3,4>::size; //Should be 4
IntList<1,2,3,4>::next; //Should be IntList<2,3,4>
```

Now, I want to use templates to create a new type which concatenates these type of lists. It will be called ConcatedIntLists.
If I need to concatenate only two lists, then it is pretty simple:

```
template<typename...>
struct ConcatedIntLists;

template<int...T1, int...T2>
struct ConcatedIntLists<IntList<T1...>, IntList<T2...>>{
    typedef IntList<T1..., T2...> list;
};
```

But what if I want to concatenate unknown number of lists? For example:

```
ConcatedIntLists<IntList<1,2,3>, IntList<>, IntList<4,5>>::list; //Should be IntList<1,2,3,4,5>
ConcatedIntLists<IntList<1>, IntList<2>, IntList<3>, IntList<4>>::list; //Should be IntList<1,2,3,4>
```

This is the part I got stuck in.

Comment: Why should the concatenation of two IntLists not simply be another IntList?

Comment: @NathanPierson You can extract it by writing "::list" at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add this extra specialization:

```
template<int...T1, typename...Ts>
struct ConcatedIntLists<IntList<T1...>, Ts...> {
    typedef typename ConcatedIntLists<IntList<T1...>,
                                      typename ConcatedIntLists<Ts...>::list>::list list;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1aYhMc).

Comment: Please add explanations to the code in your solutions. Also, it doesn't look right at all, and it's not clear to me how this solves the problem.

Comment: @cigien: It is an **extra** specialization to add. missing some extra text indeed.

Comment: @cigien Code is really self-explanatory. And it works at least in VS2019 C++17
ConcatIntList for more than 2 IntLists will call recursively itself passing first list and result of ConcatIntList on the rest of parameters... When the number of template of parameters is 2 the ConcatIntList from OP is used.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it does work, and it's a cleaner. Additional explanation is always nice to add though.

Comment: This was what I eventually have done after realizing I can simply use “typename...” instead of directly writing “IntList...”. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @dvep Actually IntList<T1...> could also be replaced with just T making this recursive definition look even simpler

Answer (score 3):

This solution was an improvement to my original solution, suggested by Jarod42 in the comments.

You can write this template recursively:

```
template<typename ...T>
struct ConcatedIntLists;  // just to allow specializations
                          // for base case, and general case 

template<typename T>
struct ConcatedIntLists<T> 
{
    using list = T;             // base case: just a list
};

// for 2 or more lists
template<int...T1, int...T2, typename ...CRest>
struct ConcatedIntLists<IntList<T1...>, IntList<T2...>, CRest...>    
{
    using list = typename ConcatedIntLists<IntList<T1..., T2...> , CRest...>::list;
                                       //  ^concatenate first two, ^and the rest      
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/snrYhn)

Note that this solution uses `using` syntax instead of `typedef` syntax, because it's much cleaner to read.

Comment: Nice and clean solution.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think so. Do you mean I could do `template<int...T1, int...T2>` for the base case?  That doesn't work.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, that's way better. I take it you don't mean to write a new answer?

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, I'll do that. I'm not sure why I got hung up on the `conditional_t` while I was playing around with it. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

These kind of things can be solved using a left fold over a list of types.
As we can't iterate over a variadic template parameter pack, we need to resort to recursion.
The code might be a bit overwhelming if you are not used to template metaprogramming, so I've put a couple of explanatory comments into the code example.

```
// This is the functor we want to fold the elements over.
// It simply concatenates two IntLists.
template<typename L1, typename L2>
struct ConcateIntListsFunctor;

// The actual functor is a so called meta function, it's arguments
// are the template parameters in the primary template. 
template<int...T1, int...T2>...
struct ConcateIntListsFunctor<IntList<T1...>, IntList<T2...>>{
    // ... and we "call" it by retrieving it's "type" typedef.
    typedef IntList<T1..., T2...> type;
};


template<template<typename, typename> class, typename...>
struct LeftFold;

// The LeftFold is a meta-function that takes a binary meta-function as first parameter, a State and a list of types we want to fold over.
template<template<typename, typename> class Func,  typename State, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct LeftFold<Func, State, T, Ts...> {
    typedef typename Func<State, T>::type NewState; 
    // Here is where the recursion happens.
    typedef typename LeftFold<Func, NewState, Ts...>::type type;  
};

template<template<typename, typename> class Func, typename State, typename T>
struct LeftFold<Func, State, T> {
    typedef typename Func<State, T>::type type;
};

template<typename L0, typename... Ls>
struct ConcatenateIntLists {
    typedef typename LeftFold<ConcateIntListsFunctor, L0, Ls...>::type type;
};
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jY7r9G).

Comment: This is quite good. I notice that your demo uses the compiler error messages to see the result. I personally think it's better to use a `static_assert` to check that types match up. It's always nice to do as much in the source code as possible. Feel free to adapt the examples in my demo if you want to.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It's just a habit as I'm doing a lot of meta programming, and this is very hand during developing as you don't have to manually type your expected type over and over. And most often I simply want to exactly what type I get and this is not always possible with a plain `static_assert`.

Comment: That type printing tool is more a debugging tool, while a static assert would be a test case. Definitely better here, I admit. But I'll leave it in the example as it might be a helpful trick in some situations.